# How can I choose which choice to show up in django form field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to dynamically change the viewable choices in a django form choice field depending on the user. Here is my form:

```
SubmitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Lesson
        fields = (
            "status",
        )
```

Here is my models.py for `Lesson`:

```
CLASS_STATUS = (
        ('Attended', 'Attended'),
        ('Absent', 'Absent'),
        ('Teacher Postponed', 'Teacher Postponed'),
        ('Student Postponed', 'Student Postponed'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=30,
        choices=CLASS_STATUS,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

So, basically I want to be able to select which choices to show for each type of user. In order to do this, I hope you guys could also show how I could access the `request.user` information in my form. Thank you, and please ask me any questions you have.

Here is a part of the view as some of you requested:

```
class SubmitView(generic.UpdateView):
    template_name = "agents/submit_form.html"
    queryset = Lesson.objects.all()
    context_object_name = "lesson"
    form_class = SubmitForm
```

Comment: Can you share the view where you use this? Exactly what property of the user should determine the list of available `status`ses?

Comment: I have updated the information above. You see, I have a couple of boolean fields for each user such as `is_teacher` or `is_student`. This is what I need to know in the form so that the form would dynamically change its choices for `status` depending on the user.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Actually, accessing the user information is not that important compared to my initial question of limiting choices.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and failed to get this working with a ModelForm. I think your best answer is to retreat to using a vanilla Form, and manually update the object. Something like

```
class Status_form( forms.Form):
    status = forms.ChoiceField( choices=Lesson.STATUS_CHOICES)

class UpdateLessonView( FormView):

    form_class = Status_form
    template_name = "agents/submit_form.html"

    def form_valid( self, form):
        self.lesson.status = form.cleaned_data['status']
        self.lesson.save()
        return redirect(
            'lessons:lesson_detail', lesson=self.lesson.pk )

    def get_form( self, form_class=None):
        self.lesson = get_object_or_404( Lesson, id=self.kwargs['lesson'] )
        self.initial = { 'status': self.wafer.status }
        form = super().get_form( form_class)

        # modify choices depending on user
        if self.request.user ... :

            status_choices=(   (..., ...), ... )

            form.fields['status'].choices = status_choices

        return form
```